# Voting during connection lost is no repeatable

Tags: discussion, bug, voting

I voted during my Internet connection lost. I was faced with a message, that there was an error and that I should repeat my request. However, my vote wasn't undone (so I could vote again) on client side, even though this request was not sent to server (recorded in database).

In this, kind of specific situation, I can't vote again (repeat request, as instructed) by simply clicking any arrow. I have to refresh entire page to get it with correct number of points and arrow enabled.

Is this a bug or by design?

Comment: I think it's a bug.